# Service Broker behind NAT and port forwarding results in "corrupted message has been received" error

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, sql-server-2017

Sending message via SQL Server Service Broker from one machine to another.

- **Sender** - Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2014 12.0.4213.0 Standard over NAT that has port forwarding for Service Broker from public IP:port to local SQL Server IP:port. Let's say, for example, the port is `26223` and it forwards to SQL Server `4022`.
- **Receiver** - CentOS 7 with SQL Server 2017 RC2 Express as web server with the same specific port opened for Service Broker. (updating to latest SQL Server CU - 14.0.3030.27 did not help)

I sent message from Sender to Receiver and firstly got error in `sys.transmission_queue` about wrong alghoritm, then I found out that I have encryption key alghoritms different on sender's and receiver's endpoints and changed receiver endpoint key encryption alghoritm to match sender's.

After that, the message I sent appeared in `sys.transmission_queue` with another error - `Service Broker/Database Mirroring network protocol error occurred.` In SQL Profiler I found more details:

> Broker:Corrupted Message - A corrupted message has been received. The binary message preamble is malformed.

On the Receiver side SQL Profiler shows that:

> Audit Broker Login: 4 - Negotiate Failure - An error occurred while receiving data: '996(Overlapped I/O event is not in a signaled state.)'.
>
> Audit Broker Login: 5 - Authentication Failure

Sometimes I also got that error at Receiver side in addition to previous:

> Audit Broker Login: 4 - Negotiate Failure - An error occurred while receiving data: '24(The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect.)'.

I have only one message for that instance waiting in `sys.transmission_queue` on Sender side.

**UPDATE:**
I used *ssbdiagnose* utility and here is what it says:

`D  29835 MainServer   MainDatabase         Messages on conversation handle 13c07ab1-6b8d-e711-80c5-002590cb2a25 (conversation id 3a7d0dd0-c957-4fe8-a98e-1cb56713023c) from service sbSenderService to service sbReceiverService cannot be transmitted dues to the following problem: Service Broker/Database Mirroring network protocol error occurred.`

`An internal exception occurred: No such host is known`

`D  29933 WebServer     WebDatabase          The routing address TCP://[NAT ip address was here]:26223 for service sbSenderService does not match any of the IP addresses for MainServer`

`An internal exception occurred: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value`

`An internal exception occurred: No such host is known
P  29945               Cannot parse the routing address: unknown`

So, the new error came into play: **The routing address TCP://[NAT ip address was here]:26223 for service sbSenderService does not match any of the IP addresses for MainServer**

As I understand it, my MainServer (Sender) does not know the NAT IP Address that is in TCP headers and marks that TCP package malformed, right? How to fix it?

**UPDATE2:** we set VPN tunnel between servers and the same errors still exists. The test CentOS server had all ports opened and no Selinux. For now I assume that Service Broker does not work between CentOS and Windows.

**UPDATE3:** updating to latest SQL Server CU on CentOS - 14.0.3030.27 did not help

Comment: If you've got the setup to spare, try the selfsame with a SQL Server 2012 Express instance on Windows as the receiver. Your current setup is bleeding edge, and may well run into some interesting corner case of cross-platform networking.

Comment: I will try a little later, thank your for advice. But do you know if it should work?

Comment: I've used Service Broker extensively, but only for local message delivery.  Never with actual transport between brokers on different machines, let alone NAT.

Comment: Service broker between Windows machines works great btw. I hope MS will fix this issue in future release of SQL Server.

Comment: They probably won't unless they're [told this doesn't work](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback). (Not that all Connect issues are picked up speedily and effectively, mind you, but at least there's a much better chance than without a report. I don't know if there's a faster feedback channel for SQL Server 2017 specifically.)

Comment: Thank you, I will post feedback.